# Show comments menu in dashboard only if the site has comment

Tags: php, menus, comments, dashboard

I would like to hide "Comments" menu in Dashboard until the site doesn't have any comments. I tried to do this with this below code, but doesn't works:

```
function remove_mainmenu_pages() {
        global $user_ID;
        if ( 1 > wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->all ) {
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_mainmenu_pages' );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Other than the `get_the_ID()` shouldn't be used there.. the code seems good. Have you tried `echo 'something';` in the function, to see if it's being called?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, it seems the echo works. I modified the code in my question. Now, the Comments menu disappear when the comment number is zero, except if I have spam or trash comments. How can I add these types to count as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution is this below to hide Comments menu if the site doesn't have any comments (approved, pending, trash or spam).

```
function remove_commentsmenu() {
        global $user_ID;
        if ( 1 > wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->total_comments && 1 > wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->trash ) {
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_commentsmenu' );
```